# How to exceed max_execution_time when running a mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysqldump

Is there any way to exceed `max_execution_time` when running `mysqldump`, without changing global `max_execution_time`? My database is in AWS RDS and I can't change these parameters for the sake of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) doesn't allow the usage of [MAX_EXECUTION_TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time) .
You can't exceed max_execution_time when running mysqldump .
This is listed as a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83339) which hasn't been solved yet.

Alternatively,(not related to the question directly) to optimize  mysqldump for a large database try using the following optins:

> [--quick,
> -q](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick)
>
> This option is useful for dumping large tables. It forces mysqldump to
> retrieve rows for a table from the server a row at a time rather than
> retrieving the entire row set and buffering it in memory before
> writing it out.
>
> [--network-timeout,
> -M](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_network-timeout)
> Enable large tables to be dumped by setting --max-allowed-packet to
> its maximum value and network read and write timeouts to a large
> value. This option is enabled by default. To disable it, use
> --skip-network-timeout.